# Is it possible to add new CSS query elements through browser extensions?

Tags: css, browser

I'd like to add query elements to CSS through a new @scroll query for example

```
@scroll document (top:30em) {
/* affect selectors */
   .FullHeader{
     max-height:0px;
   }
   .ScrolledHeader{
     max-height:30px;
   }
}
```

I am hoping to achieve element layout control when page scrolling occurs without the need for the client to write event handlers.
It would look similar to a media query but instead base off the current page left and top positions.

So, as an example, a rule like

```
@scroll document (top 30px){
  body{padding-top:30px;}
  header{position:fixed;}
}
```

would fix the header and keep body content relatively stable without additional javascript.

Is this possible through browser extensions?
Is anyone working on this or have help on how I might go about it?

Comment: How would this work exactly? Can't a global class achieve the same?

Comment: Not sure exactly how it'd work yet. @Kaiido, I'm not sure what you mean by a global class.

Comment: I understood your `@scroll` to be something like *When user is scrolling*. In this case, it could be replaced by some js like this : `window.onscroll = e => { if(!scrolling){ document.documentElement.classList.add('scroll');} if(timeout)clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = setTimeout(() => { document.documentElement.classList.remove('scroll'); scrolling= false;}, 20)};` And in your CSS, you would do `:root.scroll .some-selector{ somerules: ...}` https://jsfiddle.net/c4rcrb3a/

Comment: ... I am hoping to achieve element layout control when page scrolling occurs without the need for the client to write event handlers. It would look similar to a media query but instead base off the current page left and top positions. So, as an example, an @scoll document (top 30px){ body{padding-top:30px;} header{position:fixed;}} would fix the header and keep body content relatively stable without additional javascript.

Comment: I see better now. (You might want to include this comment in an [edit] to your question). IMK, the media-query API can't be extended, but you could probably create your own parser, like Sass does and then implement the needed rules and event listeners in js which would trigger class changes.